# Number/Word Splicer for Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to make a google spreadsheet that splits a word or string of numbers in half and puts the back half in front of the first half in a new column. However, I am new to this who process and so I came here to ask for help. I originally tried macros but couldn't get them to copy and paste information from columns.

Here is the basic idea:

[The spreadsheet cuts the number or word in half putting the back in front.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsHjy.png)

Thanks for everyone's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of an odd number of chars, `ROUNDUP` must be used in `RIGHT` or `LEFT` function:

```
=ArrayFormula(RIGHT(A1:A,ROUNDUP(LEN(A1:A)/2)) & left(A1:A,LEN(A1:A)/2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem shall be solved using the following code:

```js
=CONCATENATE(right(A2,len(A2)/2),LEFT(A2,len(A2)/2))
```

Comment: Thanks, for your response Harsh. I was in an attempt to input it in google spreadsheets but it wouldn't run. The program was saying "Unexpected token '=' ". I know this is a me problem I was just wondering what I could do to solve it.

Comment: where exactly you are trying to put this formula. You have to place this formula in every neighboring cell where you want to splice the words with 'A2' to be replaced with the cell notation to be spliced.